# How to make a block blob temporarily unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I use Azure cloud blob to serve images. Sometimes I need to make an image temporarily unavailable (ie. someone reported the image) and later may recover or delete it. How do I achieve this?

My container is public:

```
    container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

This is how I made the blob:

```
        CloudBlockBlob block_blob = ImagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob_name);

        block_blob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;
        block_blob.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=2592000";     // 30 days
        block_blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
```

Is there something like:

block_blob.Properties.AccessType = private;
block_blob.SetProperties();

so that I can make it unavailable to everyone? And later I might recover it by setting the property to "public". I can't find any properties related to this usage.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried taking a lease on the blob?

Comment: @SyntaxC4, No. But the doc says lease can only prevent "write" and "delete". However I need to prevent "read".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a public container.  I would recommend copying the blob to a private container and then deleting it from the public container, and then you can copy it back whenever you want to make it available again.  Using the Copy Blob API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx) between two containers in a single storage account will be very, very fast even for large files.

Comment: I thought this is the only way. Thanks very much.